# PHPMailer Error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. (10060)  The following From address
>   failed:id@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being
>   connected Mailer Error: The following From address failed:
>   id@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

I am not able to send email I get the above error.
Here`s the code

```
<?php require_once("Project/function/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "id@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->SetFrom("id@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->MsgHTML("Hello World");
    $mail->AddAddress("id@gmail.com");
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
        echo "Message has been sent";
        }


?>
```

I am using wamp ver 2.4.
The wamp server is offline.The Open SSL extension is enabled have checked the php.ini file the ; has been removed from open ssl dll.

Is using PEAR better?

Comment: Seems your mailing server refusing connection, perhaps the subject port is closed on you server that you tried to connect from.

Comment: my Colleges Firewall might be the reason working fine from my dongle sorry for wasting your time should have checked it from my dongle before

Comment: Great. It just happens too often due to not standard port usage. These  are true to be closed if not used.

Answer (score 3):

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

remove the ssl://

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using this works for me:

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Try getting rid of the `ssl://`

Comment: which version of wamp do you use? should wamp be put online for it to work i`m sending a mail to myself will this cause an issue

Comment: I don't use wamp, I use IIS for my webserver.  However, the only time I use this script is to email myself should my home IP change and I've done this by setting up a task in the task scheduler (which runs the script as a batch program independent of my webserver), so if you remove the `ssl://` you should have valid phpmailer code that should work (so long as your computer is connected to the internet) regardless of the webserver you are using.  The question then becomes, how do you call this script? I assume you are calling it via the command line if your wamp server is offline?

Comment: Also, I assume id@gmail.com is a dummy address you entered for the sake of the question and that you do have an actual gmail account?

Comment: Yes it is.. I actually plan to send around 600 Emails once in 6 months

Answer (score 0):

try with adding only,

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Also check PHP is using openSSL extension, you can check this in php.ini file and search extension=php_openssl.dll

```
<?php
var_dump( extension_loaded( 'openssl' ) );
?>
```

Comment: php is using open ssl will try tls

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to my College Network before.I guess the college firewall had something to do with errors.

Using Dongle to access net its working fine now.